# How to reduce spaces inside p:tabView in Primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using Primefaces V3.3.1 and want to reduce spaces inside p:tabView.
[image: layout]

In this case, I have 2 nested p:tabView and p:dataTable. And real estate of screen is very expensive for us so I would like to reduce spaces shown red and blue. So,
 question 1:How can I reduce spaces inside p:tabView (painted red)?
 question 2:How can I reduce spaces around p:dataTable (painted blue)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you should study something about css... What you call "space inside" is the padding css property, and what you call "space around" is the margin.
Anyway, to reduce the padding of tabs, add the following style to your css file:

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel {
      padding: 5px 5px;
}
```

This will reduce the panning of all your tab views. if you want this style to be applied to only some tabViews, then you should use the styleClass attribute of the tabView, and then replace the css rule  with `.youTabClass .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel`

And as for the datatable.. the datatable itself does not have margin. but it seems that in your blurry screenshot there's a panel surrounding the table. the p:panel also has padding. To reduce padding of panel:

```
.ui-panel .ui-panel-content {
     padding: 5px 5px;
}
```

And also this applies to all your panels, so you should use atyleClass to make this style specific to a panel.

Comment: @Damian, Thank you for helping me. I could reduce padding of tabs. And yes I used panel surrounding table and could reduce padding of it. Now I still have few target to reduce but I hope I can find it by myself.

Comment: @Tomcat You are welcome. to determine which css classes you need to change, take a look at primefaces guide (in every component, there's a Skinning section which names the css classes); or you can use firebug